# Any way to get a Screenshot of entire webpage WITHOUT repeating elements?

Tags: screen-capture

i use Snagit for Mac (Techsmith) to capture screenshots of entire web pages (they call it "scrolling capture") successfully.
    
-BUT-
    
on occasion, there are some webpages that do not wanna cooperate. from what i can tell, it's pages that have headers or sidebars that remain in place when the page is scrolled. these elements get captured repeatedly in the one shot - usually duplicating whole sections within the shot.

the only way i've been able to clean it up is to find the duplication & slice it out of the image. it's a pain in the ass for long pages.

at first, i thought it was a Snagit issue. but after downloading & trying multiple other full-page screenshot programs & browser extensions, it happens with all of them - on any browser.

so, i've attempted doing a developer inspection of the code & deleting those sections, or trying to find the scripts that make those areas stay static on the pages, but have been unsuccessful. 
i've also tried using the QuickNuke extension - but still, no luck.

anybody got any other hacks, ideas, apps, extensions, that can workaround this?
thanx!

Comment: my most recent example & need for a whole-page-screenshot is http://www.texastribune.org/public-ed/explore/lago-vista-isd ...first note: all the analytics on the page doesn't load until you scroll down thru them all. and secondly, the top head & sidebar stickies take various whole sections & repeat/duplicate within the shot, making it a HUGE chore to edit out afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [Paparazzi](http://derailer.org/paparazzi/) and it works fine taking full-length screenshots of webpages with fixed elements, as far as I can tell.

Comment: my most recent example & need for a whole-page-screenshot is http://www.texastribune.org/public-ed/explore/lago-vista-isd ...first note: all the analytics on the page doesn't load until you scroll down thru them all. and secondly, the top head & sidebar stickies take various whole sections & repeat/duplicate within the shot, making it a HUGE chore to edit out afterwards. ...i've tried this with Paparazzi with no success. does it work for you?

Comment: Actually it does, but it's a little tricky. First, enter the URL and let it do the initial capture. Then click the hand icon at the bottom left of the window to open an interactive view of the page (basically an embedded browser). Scroll down the page gradually to trigger each of the graphs to load. Finally, once you hit the bottom of the page, click "Close and Capture" and the entire thing will be saved as one huge image...tada!

Comment: BRILLIANT!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH for pointing that feature out to me. i had no idea. you rock! it worked it worked it worked :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [Screen Capture](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screen-capture-by-google/cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg) by Google. Maybe it's help.

Comment: Confirmed this works for me.

Comment: my most recent example & need for a whole-page-screenshot is http://www.texastribune.org/public-ed/explore/lago-vista-isd ...first note: all the analytics on the page doesn't load until you scroll down thru them all. and secondly, the top head & sidebar stickies take various whole sections & repeat/duplicate within the shot, making it a HUGE chore to edit out afterwards. ...does Screen Capture work for you on this page?